# how can i reproduce the 'Unity_Matrix_VP' value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, shader, transform

I wan't to calculate the Unity_Matrix_VP in C# code.

But, always I got the incorrect result. My code as follow:

```
     Matrix4x4 V = camera1.worldToCameraMatrix;
     Matrix4x4 P = camera1.projectionMatrix;
     var N = new Matrix4x4();
     N.SetRow(0, new Vector4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
     N.SetRow(1, new Vector4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
     N.SetRow(2, new Vector4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f));
     N.SetRow(3, new Vector4(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f));
     Debug.Log("testCamera");
     Debug.Log(N);
     Debug.Log(P * N * V);
```

My Code result is:

`0.97384    -0.02902    0.00304    3.04939
 0.05073    1.72168    0.18231    179.67620
 0.00624    0.10518    -0.99504    -990.16710
 0.00623    0.10512    -0.99444    -989.57320`

But, the value of Unity_Matrix_VP from FrameDebugger is another value:

[Frame Debugger Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHUoG.png)

It's very amazing. Could Unity calculate the unity_Matrix_VP value via another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it:

Because the Unity C# use the OpenGL standard and I run Unity on Windows.

So it will translate the Matrix_PV to DirectX。

It can fixed by API of '[GL.GetGPUProjectionMatrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-PlatformDifferences.html)' to cross platform.